# Why would a GitLab pipeline only run the last stage when triggered by a merge request?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

The pipeline runs successfully with all stages when I click "Run pipeline" but when run for a merge request it only runs the last job which is the last stage. That last job has dependencies on the first 2 stages. There is at least 1 job in each stage that has no rules.

Comment: Please include your gitlab ci yaml for reference. That would help others to check what exactly are your stages/jobs doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is at least 1 job in each stage that has no rules.

If a job has no rules, it won't run on a merge request pipeline. As noted in [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html):

> Merge request pipelines:
>
> - Do not run by default. The jobs in the CI/CD configuration file [must be configured](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html#prerequisites) to run in merge request pipelines.

You need to make sure all your jobs are configured for merge request pipelines. The way you configure this is using `rules:`.